# Is it possible to use GCC's '__builtin_avr_delay_cycles' in the assembler?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, avr, avr-gcc

Sory for bad English, please.

I need write a time-critical piece of code (a strict part of software protocol implementation via bit-bang) that uses delays. C preprocessor at the compile time can compute the number of clock cycles (with `F_CPU` macro) for a delay, so I need to implement a assembler delay code for *unknown* number of cycles.

But GCC provide very useful function `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles(unsigned long cycles)` that make delay *exactly* `cycles` clock cycles for defined `F_CPU` frequency.

**Question**. Is there way to use `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles` *within* inline-assembler code?

**Note**. Bypass way is like this:

```
__asm__ (...);
__builtin_avr_delay_cycles(...);
__asm__ (...);
```

but the compiler can make some code around `__asm__` pieces. It is bad for me, I need to control each clock cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, compiler built-ins are not real functions and cannot be called from assembler, nor will the compiler recognise them within assembler.

Answer (score 2):

```
__asm__ (...);
__builtin_avr_delay_cycles(...);
__asm__ (...);
```

Compile the code like this and then look at what the compiler emitted for the builtin.

It will be a sequence very similar to the following:

```
   ldi R2,lo8(N)
   ldi R3,hi8(N)
   ldi R4,hlo8(N)
1: subi R2,1
   sbci R3,0
   sbci R4,0
   brne 1b"
```

There may be a 2-3 such sequences, sometimes ending with `nopv` insn, sometimes there will be 1 or 2 or 3 `ldi` and `sbci` insns, you get the pattern (it depends on the cycles count).

Turn these insns into inline assembly, `N` is the cycles count, `Rn` are registers.

The drawback is that generated code depends on the cycle count and if it changes, you'll have to repeat the process. However, you're safe if the change is within one of the following ranges:  [83886082, 0xFFFFFFFF], [262145, 83886081], [768, 262144], [6, 767].